# react-router-dom doesn't work with certain routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm sorry about the question, maybe this has already been sent somewhere, but I haven't found anything.

I have a react project with a `webpack.config.js`.

I'm using the react-router-dom library to do the routes in the project, but I'm having a little problem.

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path={"/"} component={IndexComponent} />
                <Route path={"/:username"} component={HomeUser} />
                <Route path={"/:username/manager"} component={UserManager} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    , document.getElementById("react-root")
);
```

So you can see that I have 3 routes: the first one is the main "/", and it works.
The second one is "/:username" and when I write something like `http://localhost:8080/blablabla` the render method works.
Now the third one. When I write `http://localhost:8080/blablabla/manager` the render method doesn't work and I see a white page.

I'm not understanding where is the error. Something in the webpack? Or maybe it needs a server configuration?

In the webpack I have this about the devserver:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
},
```

About the plugins I'm using the HtmlWebPackPlugin, and about the module and rules I'm using babel-loader, html-loader, style-loader, css-loader, and file-loader.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your

```
<Route path={"/:username/manager"} component={UserManager} />
```

needs to on top of

```
<Route path={"/:username"} component={HomeUser} />
```

so like this:

```
<Switch>
     <Route exact path={"/"} component={IndexComponent} />
     <Route exact path={"/:username/manager"} component={UserManager} />
     <Route path={"/:username"} component={HomeUser} />
</Switch>
```

And I believe that you need to put `exact` on the second one as well

Let me know if it helps, cheers

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.
I tried it - I forgot to write in the question - and nothing.. it doesn't work. Also if I remove the /:username path.

Answer (score 0):

[Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) only returns the first matched `Route` or `Redirect`.

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

## Issue

The issue is that you've specified less specific routes *before* more specific routes. Routes are matched by "prefix", meaning "/" will match ***all*** routes (thus the need to usually specify the `exact` prop), "/:username" will also match any sub-routes. The `Router` component typically uses the `exact` prop since it can match ***and*** render multiple matches whereas the `Switch` will only ever match and render a single match.

## Solution

Order your paths by specificity, more specific to more general. This will allow the more specific paths to match first, then fallback to a less specific route if a match isn't found.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={"/:username/manager"} component={UserManager} />
    <Route path={"/:username"} component={HomeUser} />
    <Route path={"/"} component={IndexComponent} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Generally you can also include a last 404 component for the case that literally *nothing* matches any route your app handles.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path={"/:username/manager"} component={UserManager} />
    <Route path={"/:username"} component={HomeUser} />
    <Route path={"/"} component={IndexComponent} />
    <Route component={FourOhFour} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: Ok, I fixed adding `output: {
    publicPath: "/"
  }` in webpack.

Comment: Thanks, @Stackedo adding publicPath property to webpack configuration file resolve the issue. It is important to clarify that order paths from more specific to less specific it is a rule that must be followed. My issue was more related to the path where the files were built and when I was navigating to another route the built files were not in that route.